# Seat Reservation

Tags: php, html

I've created a seat booking website and here is a simplified bit of the code that draws out the seats. I have an array called "booked" which contains the seats which are booked. 
How do I change the div tag id to "booked" whenever the seat number is equal to any of the numbers in the "booked" array?

```
<?php
$rows = 20;
$cols = 10;
$currentnr;
$booked = array(1, 4, 100, 199);

echo "<table border='1'>";
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){ // Going through every row
    echo "<tr>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td += 2){ // Going through every column (2 at a time)
            $currentnr = ($tr * 10 - 10 + $td); // Calculates the current nr
            // ---------This id \/
            echo "<td><div id='free'><p>".$currentnr."</p></div></td>";
            echo "<td><div id='free'><p>".($currentnr + 1)."</p></div></td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at the `in_array` function - http://uk1.php.net/in_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
echo "<td><div id='" . (in_array($currentnr, $booked) ? 'booked' : 'free') . "'><p>".$currentnr."</p></div></td>";
```

But also you should use `class` instead of `id`, since there are more of them.